# How to parse this file in Python?

Tags: python, parsing

How to parse this file in Python ?Basically is there any module in Python to do this job? Eg. I need to get Index_Size from  NFSv4_ClientId_Cache from the example below . Assume the below contents are in a file called "file1".

```
    NFSv4_ClientId_Cache
{
    Prealloc_Node_Pool_Size = 1000;
    Index_Size = 47;
    Alphabet_Length = 256;
}
NFS_DupReq_Hash
{
    Prealloc_Node_Pool_Size = 1000;
    Index_Size = 47;
    Alphabet_Length = 256;
}
```

Comment: Parse it to what?

Comment: Edited the question .Please answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get the `Index_Size` integer between the `NFSv4_ClientId_Cache`  braces and store it.

```
import re
index_size = 0
with open('file', 'r') as f:
   text = f.read()
   top_level = 'NFSv4_ClientId_Cache'
   field_name = 'Index_Size'
   result = re.search(r'%s.*?\{.*?%s.*?(\d+).*?\}' % (top_level, field_name), text, re.DOTALL)
   index_size = result.group(1)

print index_size
> 47
```

Comment: Can' we do this with any existing python module?

Comment: @VasanthGowda I seriously doubt it. What you're asking is to extract an arbitrary string of text from an arbitrary format. If your text was in JSON or any other well-specified format then yes there probably is a module for it. But right now you'll need to specify the format yourself through regex or some other handcrafted way.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point.